# System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an VSTO Outlook Add-in. In the compose windows I have a button which removes all the recipients that satify a condition.

Below the code of the button click event:

```
    private void ClickButton(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Outlook.Recipient> toList = new List<Outlook.Recipient>();
        List<Outlook.Recipient> CCList = new List<Outlook.Recipient>();
        List<Outlook.Recipient> BCCList = new List<Outlook.Recipient>();

        Outlook.Recipient recipient = null;
        Outlook.Recipients recipients = this.MyMailItem?.Recipients;
        for (int i = recipients?.Count ?? 1; i > 0; i -= 1)
        {
            recipient = recipients[i];
            if (!this.recipientsList.Contains(recipient))
            {
                if (recipient.Type == (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo)
                {
                    toList.Add(recipient);
                }
                else if (recipient.Type == (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC)
                {
                    CCList.Add(recipient);
                }
                else if (recipient.Type == (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC)
                {
                    BCCList.Add(recipient);
                }
            }

            Marshall.ReleaseComObject(recipient);
            recipient = null;
        }

        this.MyMailItem.To = null;
        this.MyMailItem.CC = null;
        this.MyMailItem.BCC = null;

        if (toList != null && toList.Count > 0)
        {
            MyMailItem.To = string.Join(";", this.GetRecipientsAsString(toList));
        }

        if (CCList != null && CCList.Count > 0)
        {
            MyMailItem.CC = string.Join(";", this.GetRecipientsAsString(CCList));
        }

        if (BCCList != null && BCCList.Count > 0)
        {
            MyMailItem.BCC = string.Join(";", this.GetRecipientsAsString(BCCList));
        }

        this.recipientsList.Clear();
    }
```

Note that recipientsList is a global variable of type List<Outlook.Recipient>.

```
    private List<string> GetRecipientsAsString(List<Outlook.Recipient> recipientsList)
    {
        List<string> recList = null;
        if (recipientsList?.Count > 0)
        {
            recList = new List<string>();
            foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in recipientsList)
            {
                recList.Add(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recipient.Name) ? recipient.Address : recipient.Name);
            }
        }

        return recList;
    }
```

Sometimes, not always, i am receiving below exception:

```
COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
```

This is thrown in GetRecipientsAsString method at this line:

```
recList.Add(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recipient.Name) ? recipient.Address : recipient.Name);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you get rid of the Marshall.ReleaseComObject line?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I haven't tried by removing that line but I guess you always should release COM objects in that way, right? If i remove that line, that COM object is never released???

Comment: No, GC will release that object at a later point. `Marshall.ReleaseComObject` is for immediate reelase if you process a large number of objects, e.g. hundreds of messages in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping Outlook COM objects in the collection is the source of problems. For example, when you set the `To`, `Cc` or `Bcc` properties the `Recipients` collection is updated, i.e. old recipient instances are destroyed and new ones are created/added. So, your Recipient objects stored in a list are getting obsolete and calling any properties or methods in the `GetRecipientsAsString` function could lead to exceptions like yours.

Instead, I'd recommend keeping a list of email addresses or names. In that case you can re-create a recipient instance if required by using the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) function of the `Namespace` class.

Comment: Yeap, the problem was keeping Outlook COM objects in a list collection. Sometimes recipients were deleted and sometimes not, that is, randomly. Also it was throwing COM exceptions randomly. So as you said finally I opt to change all the list keeping Outlook COM objects to keep a list of email addresses or names (display names). Now it seems it is working, the recipients are deleted correctly and no COM exception anymore.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer on other posts where a similar topic was covered.